# Serial to send data to ardiuno from C# APP

Tags: c#, arduino, connection

I have trouble with application with sending data(two trackbars positions) to set PWM frequency and Voltage. I wrote this in arduino:

```
#include <PWM.h>
#include <Servo.h>
int led = 9;
int32_t frequency = 100;


void setup() 
    {
        InitTimersSafe();
        bool success = SetPinFrequencySafe(led, frequency);
    }


void loop() 
    {
        //pwmWrite(led, 124);
        int channel;
        int freq;
        int Pwm;
        pwmWrite(led, Pwm);
        channel = Serial.readStringUntil(':').toInt();

        if (channel = 1)
            {
                Pwm = Serial.readStringUntil('*').toInt();
                pwmWrite(led,Pwm);
            }
        else if (channel = 2)
            {
                freq = Serial.readStringUntil('*').toInt(); 
                frequency = freq;
                pwmWrite(led,Pwm);
            }
    }
```

I've seacrhed milion websites, rode serial references and still it doesn't work.

The C# app has connection (COM3) and i see the data transfer when I moving the trackbar.

the C# code:

```
        private void trackBar2_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string bar2 = trackBar2.Value.ToString();
            label2.Text = bar2;
            int freq = trackBar2.Value;
            //port.WriteLine(trackBar2.Value.ToString()); 
            SendFrequencyInfo(1, freq);  
        }

    private void SendFrequencyInfo(int frequency, int trackBar2Pos)
    {   

          string message = frequency.ToString() + ':' + trackBar2Pos.ToString() + '*';

        try
            {
                port.Write(message);

            }
        catch
            {

            }
    }
```

The question is:
How to send two values via Serial connection (two trackbar values) to setup frequency and PWM voltage?
Did I miss something, I don't really.
Please help me :)

Answer (score 0):

I think, you should rethink your 'protocol'. Every message should be one line. Read the whole line and use sscanf (http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=43247.0) to extract your values out of the string. Something like `sscanf(Serial.ReadLine(), "%d:%d", &channel, &frequency)` should make your logic easier. Check if sscanf is returning 2 (2 variables parsed) and if all variables are set, call pwmWrite(..)

Also you mixed your parameters in the C# SendMethod

Comment: ah I see my mistake in C# code, can you tell me code without this mistake (switched paramameters) is this code should works fine? :)